# Show Simplified Directives

Tags: simplifying-expressions, output-formatting, color

Is there a way to force Mathematica to convert an already rendered Graphic to the simplified Directive form of that Graphic.

**Background:** I am currently editing Graphics using Drawing Tools and then calling `InputForm[gr]`, but this often doesn't work well because the output of `InputForm` are much larger then the original input.

For example I am looking for the following code

```
gr = Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}];
InputForm[gr]
```

To output the simplest form possible.

For example `HoldForm[InputForm[gr]]` could print `Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}]` or `Graphics[{Red, Circle[0,0]}]`.

**EDIT:** There are a lot of Graphic directives listed in the docs, so there probably isn't a direct answer, but simply answers that get closer to respecting the original input.  The best technique IMO would somehow create a trained function which evolves based on the version of Mathematica that you are currently using.  Obviously manual transformation are less then ideal.

Comment: I'm not sure what you're asking, can you clarify?  Do you just want to get `Red` instead of `RGBColor[1,0,0]`?  Can you show what `InputForm` shows you and point out specifically what you don't like about it?

Comment: @Szabolcs small typo.  It should have said `InputForm[gr]`.  Halirutan and I have been discussing this in the chat room.  Ultimately I would like the output of `InputForm[gr]` to be a close to the original input as possible.  Currently the ouptut is `Graphics[{RGBColor[1, 0, 0], Circle[{0, 0}]}]` instead of `Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}]`.  There are a lot of Graphic directives listed in the docs, so there probably isn't a direct answer, but simply answers that get closer to respecting the original input.

Comment: It's probably just a typo, but `Graphics[{Red, Circle[0, 0]}]` is invalid syntax.

Comment: I would like to nominate this question for **reopening**.  Even though it is a bit misguided I think it is interesting.

Comment: I unilaterally reopened this question because in a year and a half no one either voted or comment on my proposal to reopen, as far as I can tell.  If the community wishes to close this again I shall not overrule.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This strikes me as a flawed question (sorry) as you are converting between forms that are not entirely equivalent.  I mean that for example there are a number of different sets of named colors, and you cannot ultimately know what set may have been used to create the `Graphics` therefore you cannot "put Humpty Dumpty together again."

Nevertheless if we are going to attempt this I think I can give cleaner code that what halirutan provided:

```
rules = MakeExpression@# /. _[x_] :> #2 :> x & @@@ ColorData["Legacy", "ColorRules"];
AppendTo[rules, Circle[] :> Circle[]];
```

Now:

```
gr = Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}];
HoldForm @@ {InputForm@gr} /. rules
```

> ```
> Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}]
> ```

Comment: This isn't an attempt to retrieve the original input, but instead have a cleaner more pleasant output to look at.  I have modified your code slightly.  Is there a way to get a list of shapes that have default parameters?  I am currently manually listing them like the following `Map[(#[] :> #[]) &, {Circle, Rectangle, Disk,Cylinder, Sphere, Cone, Tube}]`

Comment: @Liam That makes more sense to me now; thanks.  Regarding shapes, no, not that I am aware of; I'd do it the same way you are.

Answer (score 3):

As discussed in chat, one way to revert the colors to their names is to use [`ColorData`](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/ColorData.html) to create a list of named colors and inject them back into your held graphics:

```
rules = Cases[
   MakeExpression[#] /.
      HoldComplete[expr_] :> (HoldPattern[Evaluate[expr]] :> expr) & /@
     ColorData["HTML", "ColorFunction"][[3, 1]],
   HoldPattern[Verbatim[HoldPattern][_RGBColor] :> _]];

gr = Graphics[{Red, Circle[]}];
With[{expr = InputForm[gr]},
 HoldForm[expr] /. rules
]
```